# For sufficiently large $n$ there exists a locally linear $n$-vertex graph with at least $mn^{3/2}$ edges for small $m$

Tags: graph-theory

Here is the definition of *locally linear graph*.

> A graph is *locally linear* if every edge lies in exactly one triangle.

I want to prove the following statement:

> For sufficiently large n, there exists a locally linear n-vertex graph with at least $mn^{3/2}$ edges for a constant $m$.

Here, $m$ can be sufficiently small, for example, $m=\frac{1}{100}$.
I tried two strategies:

1. Use the results related to [Ruzsa–Szemerédi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruzsa%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_problem#cite_note-seb73-8)
2. Suppose there exists an edge that is not in a triangle or in two triangles. 
   Assume $n$ is sufficiently large and reach a  contradiction.

But unfortunately, both did not work well.
Also, I found a result of [Paul erdős](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1973-15.pdf) which claims the maximum number of such $3$-tuples can be $\Omega(n^{3/2})$ according to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruzsa%E2%80%93Szemer%C3%A9di_problem#cite_note-seb73-8).
However, I could not understand his paper, and I think it does not give something useful to the proof.
Would you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What does "did not work well" mean? The lower bound section of the Wikipedia article you link to seems to say exactly how to do this.

Comment: @MishaLavrov You mean, constructing a tripartite graph? Of course I tried it, but it 'did not work well', i.e. I failed to describe it into rigorous proof.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about which parts of the tripartite graph argument you are unhappy with? What Wikipedia has *is* a rigorous proof by some standards, it just might not go into as much detail as you want in places; which gaps do you need filled in?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry for late response. I understood how to construct locally-linear graph, but I am not sure how it implies the statement - is it related to the number of edges?